# $f, \hat{f} \in L^{p}(\mathbb R) \cap C(\mathbb R) \implies |f(x)| \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose $f, \hat{f} \in L^{p}(\mathbb R) \cap C(\mathbb R)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R), (1<p<\infty).$

**My Question**: Can we expect $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} |f(x)|=0$ ?
(In other words, If $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ both are in  $L^{p} $ space and continuous , does it mean that $f$ vanishes at infinity)

[We note that for $p=1,$ the result follows from Riemann Lebsgue lemma, and inversion formula]

**Edit:** If needed, additionally, we assume $f$ is  in $A(\mathbb T),$  that is, if we restrict to $f$ to finite interval, say $[0, 2\pi] \subset \mathbb R,$  then $\hat{f} \in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z),$ that is, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty.$

***Edit again:*** We assume that  $f\in \mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ means that $\phi f \in A(\mathbb T)$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $\phi $ is compactly supported in $[0, 2\pi)$ (or in general case any interval I of length $2\pi$ ).  With this assumption can we expect $|f(x)|\to 0 $ as $|x|\to \infty$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this doesn't follow. Fix a smooth bump function $\varphi$ supported in $[-1,1]$ and let 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(2^n x-n)
$$
The $n$th term is supported in $[n-2^{-n}, n+2^{-n}]$; these supports are disjoint. The series converges in every $L^p$ space. The function $f$ does not tend to zero at infinity, through.

On the Fourier side, 
$$
\hat f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\hat \phi(2^{-n} \xi)e^{i \text{(something)}}
$$
(The last term is unimodular, so I don't care what it is.) The $n$th term has $L^p$ norm 
$$2^{-np}2^n \|\hat \phi\|_p$$
so the series converges in every $L^p$ space with $p>1$. It also converges uniformly, so the sum  is continuous.

---

The function $f$ in this example is $C^\infty$, and therefore belongs to any reasonable local function space that doesn't require analyticity.

Comment: thanks; Concerning last remark: there exists a  [triangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) which is not identically zero and and when we restrict this function to any interval of length $2\pi$ (say for instance), it has an absolutely convergent  Fourier series.

Comment: What I meant to say is $f$ is locally in $\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R)=\{f\in L^{\infty}: \hat{f}\in L^{1}\}.$ Then can we expect $|f(x)|\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$?

Comment: Kindly would please tell me something concerning this?

Comment: No, if you restrict that function to an interval such that its values at the endpoints are not the same, the Fourier series will not be absolutely convergent. Absolute convergence of a series on on $[a,b]$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: Same for your second comment. There is no reasonable notion of "locally" in $\mathcal FL^1$ .  If you restrict a positive smooth function, e.g., a Gaussian, to an interval, the Fourier transform of the restriction will not be in $L^1$.

Comment: thanks; I am wondering about this: if I take $f(x)=e^{-x^{2}},$ for $x\in [0, 2\pi],$ then $\hat{f}\notin \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, this is this true.

Comment: @Yes: Actually, there is a (more or less) reasonable definition of being locally in $\mathcal{F}L^p$ for any $p \in[1,\infty]$. We say that $f$ is locally at $x$ in that space if there is a test function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$ with $\varphi \equiv 1$ in a neighbourhood of $x$ and such that $\varphi f$ is in $\mathcal{F}L^p$. There are also some types of spaces defined using this idea, e.g. certain Wiener Amalgam spaces.

Comment: @PhoemueX;  thanks: Can we expect  Wiener amalgam spaces $W^{p,1}(\mathbb R^{d}) \subset C_{0}(\mathbb R^{d})$ ? for $1<p<\infty$. (Note. It is true that $W^{p,1}(\mathbb R^{d}) \subset C(\mathbb R)$.)

Comment: @Yes: thanks,  I have edited the question, please  have a look  at it.  Now can we expect some thing?

Comment: @Inquisitive: I don't think that we have $W^{p,1}(\Bbb{R}^d)\subset C$ as you claim. Consider for example $p=2$. Then the Wiener norm is (thanks to Plancherel) equivalent to $\sum_n \int_{[n,n+1]} |f|^2\,dx$ and there are certainly functions for which this is finite but which are not continuous. But for $p=1$, the result holds.

Comment: @PhoemueX; thanks;  Please the [Remark 1.2 (2), p.6](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0519v2.pdf)

Comment: In that paper we can weight $w(x, \xi)=w(x)=1;$ please correct me if I have made any mistake.

Comment: @Inquisitive The function $f$ in my example is $C^\infty$, so it's in any local space you want.

Comment: @Inquisitive: I am not really sure about that remark. First of all note (cf. before equation (1.2)) that Toft **always** uses the $q$-exponent (not $p$) for the frequency variable $\xi$. Thus, his assumption $q=1$ would be $p=1$ in my/your notation. Even then, it is not hard to see that the Wiener space (with local conponent $\mathcal{F}L^1$ and global component $\ell^q$) is contained in $C_0$.